# Low frequency driver replacement for BX5a

Tags: monitors, replacement-parts

Any idea where I can get a replacement low-frequency driver for my M-Audio BX5a monitor?  One of my monitors has been making a fuzz noise on a few low frequencies.

M-Audio has been no help.  Full Compass carries [the high-frequency driver](http://www.fullcompass.com/product/342851.html)... I've seen the woofer online be in the past, but can't find one now.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I called the number above, then was told by recording I needed an AVID support code. I pressed "2" and actually talked with a customer support rep, and was told to email my request to "repairs@m-audio.com"   BTW is tried several times to get this email address from the M-audio website but was unable to find it.

Comment: Good find!  I sent them an e-mail.  I'll let you know what I hear back.

Comment: Wow, not but an hour after I e-mailed them, they sent me back an order form.  $22 for the replacement.  Thanks for finding this e-mail address!!

Answer (score 1):

I may have stumbled on a better way to contact M-Audio, that I will try next week.  I can order parts from their repair department.  For anyone interested, here is their info:

> Call 626-633-9055, press 2 at any time to bypass the introduction message, and then press 2 for replacement parts.
>
> Mon - Fri, 9am - 5pm, Pacific Time